# SWE Train with 49 euro ticket

Tags: trains, germany, public-transport, france, deutschlandticket

Can we use the 49 euro Deutschland ticket for SWE RB25 that goes from Offenburg, Germany to Strasbourg, France?

The stops in between are Kork, Kehl, Krimmeria Meinau (all of them are in Germany). Strasbourg is the first stop after the border.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145401/discussion-on-question-by-x89-swe-train-with-49-euro-ticket); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed. All comments so far should have been posted as an answer (and possibly comments on that answer.) Post answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is a [list of which routes the Deutschlandticket is valid on](https://deutschlandtarifverbund.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/20230505_TB-D-Ticket_Geltungsbreich.pdf#page=14), and the only routes in France (on page 14) are:

- Berg(Pfalz) – Lauterbourg (on DB Regio trains)
- Schweighofen – Wissembourg (on DB Regio or Vlexx trains)

Point 3 of the document also states that the Deutschlandticket is valid on all routes of the various Verkehrsverbünde listed, but as far as I can see from eg https://www.ortenaulinie.de/Startseite/Verbundgebiet/Tarifzonen.html, Strasbourg is not included in that area.

You can of course buy a ticket from the last station which your ticket does cover to Strasbourg, rather than needing a separate ticket to cover the entire journey.

Answer (score 3):

I have the exact answer and it's YES! You can use a 49 euro ticket on this transport, but only to Kehl. If you go to Strasbourg, you will have to buy a separate ticket.

I too was looking for the answer and looking here I believed an earlier comment left. But right now I got an answer from TGO, the company that runs the SWE trains, and they told me what I wrote in the beginning - you can use the 49€ ticket.

Text of letter:

> Sehr geehrte Frau *********,
>
> das Deutschland Ticket hat auch Gültigkeit in den Zügen der SWEG – von
> Offenburg bis nach Kehl!!
>
> Für die Weiterfahrt nach Strasbourg ist eine extra Fahrkarte
> erforderlich.
>
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen,
>
> Ihr TGO Team
>
> ---
>
> TGO-Tarifverbund Ortenau GmbH E-Mail: tgo@ortenaulinie.de

Translation to English: (using Google Translate)

> Dear Ms. *********,
>
> The Germany Ticket is also valid on SWEG trains – from Offenburg to
> Kehl!!
>
> An extra ticket is required for the onward journey to Strasbourg.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Your TGO team
>
> TGO-Tariffverbund Ortenau GmbH Email: tgo@ortenaulinie.de

P.s. Yes, the reply said SWEG trains, I don't really know the difference between the two, but as I understood from their website, it's all their company's trains, including SWE. Plus I asked exactly about SWE RB25